# I can't seem to find out how to fix my npm issue

Tags: npm, terminal

So I have been trying to install various NPM packages over the pack week but my terminal keeps giving me an error message which looks like this:

```
    R! Darwin 16.1.0
    npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm"     "install" "-g" "browserify"
    npm ERR! node v6.6.0
    npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
    npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/JSONStream-fcd46b7f
    npm ERR! code EACCES
    npm ERR! errno -13
    npm ERR! syscall rmdir

   npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, rmdir   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/JSONStream-fcd46b7f'
  npm ERR!     at Error (native)
  npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, rmdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/JSONStream-fcd46b7f'
 npm ERR!     at Error (native)
 npm ERR!   errno: -13,
 npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
 npm ERR!   syscall: 'rmdir',
 npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/JSONStream-  fcd46b7f' }
 npm ERR! 
  **strong text**npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
```

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:

I have been trying to read through the error messages and searching Google and Stack overflow but can seem to find an answer. 
Does anyone know what is going on and how to fix it? I understand it states "Please try running this command again as root/Adminstrator" which I think I am already doing.

Comment: What OS?  Are you logged in as **root**?  Are you using **sudo npm install**?

Comment: Yes I am using sudo npm install.

Comment: I am not sure if i'm logged in as root. do you know how I can check this?

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41670317/npm-command-issue